# Is there any difference in meaning between the phrase "clear the air" and "have it out with someone"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Is there any difference in meaning between the phrase *clear the air* and *have it out with someone*? For example:

> I think it's time to **clear the air** with Kate.
>
> I think it's time to **have it out** with Kate.

According to the Macmillan Dictionary, [*clear the air*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/clear-the-air) and [*have it out with*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-out) basically have the same meaning, except they have different wording. Or do they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can both mean confronting someone you have a problem with, but "have it out with" can suggest an *argument* or even a *fight*, whereas "clear the air" is more positive and suggests seeking a *resolution*.

True, an argument can lead to a resolution, but not always. Stating your intention to "clear the air" certainly sounds like you have the intention of achieving a peaceable outcome.

Comment: +1 for a crucial distinction.